# Duplicate for auto increment field of mysql entityframework core

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I used db-scaffold to scaffold my database

then when I tried to add one entry,

```
 Users merchant = new Users {Name = name, PrivateKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Address = address, Role = "agent" };
        context.Add(merchant);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

this error resulted
`MySqlException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'`

I tried to verify the number of entries in my table using `context.Users.Count()`, it returns 6

then I tried to do this

```
 Users merchant = new Users { Id=context.Users.Count()+1, Name = name, PrivateKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Address = address, Role = "agent" };
        context.Add(merchant);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

However, the same error still resulted...

This is the generated class of my table

```
public partial class Users
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string PrivateKey { get; set; }
    }
```

other than id theres no other private keys in the table, which is obvious

Comment: Why do you create a Guid that is not an identifier?  Also, couldn't you have the same count for awhile in the code until the entity is actually saved, causing multiple users to exists with same id before committed?

Comment: @Greg that field need to have no collision. For same count issue, count=6 was like there for a week and I am adding a new entry an hour ago, but the entry have pkey of 2. would I be due to I filtered the table with where clause?

Comment: add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute to your Id property and migrate it to your database.

Comment: @Eldar I am using a DB-first approach, I already have AI specified in my DB.

Comment: Check your generated SQL it may be adding sth like `Identity Insert On`. And either way you should add the attribute or config so it matches the database.